# An explicit isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^+ \times {\rm Spin}(3,1)$ and ${\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R})\times {\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: group-theory

I am interested in the following isomorphism

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{R}^+\times {\rm Spin}(3,1)& \cong \mathbb{R}^+\times {\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C})\cong {\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{C})\cong {\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R}) \times {\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R})
\end{align}
$$

The last line comes from my understanding that $\mathfrak{gl}^+(2,\mathbb{C})=\mathfrak{gl}^+(2,\mathbb{R})+i \mathfrak{gl}^+(2,\mathbb{R})$

---

I am now trying to find an explicit form of the isomorphism.

---

1. 

My attempt so far:

Expanded as a matrix I get

$$
\mathfrak{gl}^+(2,\mathbb{R})+i \mathfrak{gl}^+(2,\mathbb{R})= \begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}+i \begin{bmatrix} e&f\\g&h\end{bmatrix}
$$

For the $\mathbb{R}^+\times {\rm Spin}(3,1)$, I get

$$
\mathfrak{so}(3,1)= \{ \sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3, i\sigma_1,i\sigma_2,i\sigma_3, \}
$$

times $\mathbb{R}$, I get 7 parameters, versus 8 parameters.

This is the point I need help. Either I made a mistake somewhere, or I do not know how its possible to have an isomorphism between a 7 parameter group and a 8 parameter group.

---

2. 

Another thing I noticed is that

$$
\exp (\mathfrak{gl}(2,\mathbb{R})) 
$$

does not commute with
$$
\exp (i \mathfrak{gl}(2,\mathbb{R})) 
$$

and this may negatively affect its identification as the lie algebra ${\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R}) \times {\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R}).

---

3. 

EDIT:: OHHHH I GET IT.

this lane is false:

$$
\mathbb{R}^+\times {\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C})\cong {\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{C})
$$

because it is $\mathbb{C}^+\times {\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C})\cong {\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{C})$. The scalar ought to be a complex, not a real.

Comment: These groups are not isomorphic. As I already said in the comments to your other question, the real and imaginary part decomposition is *not* a Lie algebra direct sum decomposition. $i \mathfrak{gl}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not a Lie subalgebra at all and you can check this for yourself by computing some brackets.

Comment: Every isomorphism in your first line is correct, except the last one. As for your third edit, the isomorphism $\Bbb R^+\times{\rm SL}_2\Bbb C\cong{\rm GL}^+_2\Bbb C$ is true. There is no $\Bbb C^+$.

Answer (score 1):

As @QiaochuYuan comments, there are some problems with what you'd originally hoped to prove.

A somewhat general discussion of the (theoretically well-known) *mechanisms* of some larger families including the corrected version of your approximate isomorphism is available at

[https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/sporadic_isogenies.pdf](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/v/sporadic_isogenies.pdf)