# Explicit isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^+ \times {\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$ and ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: group-theory, clifford-algebras

I am looking for an explicit isomorphism between these two groups:

$$
\mathbb{R}^+ \times {\rm Spin}^c(3,1) \cong {\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{C})
$$

---

If it makes a difference, I am using this representation for  $\mathbb{R}^+ \times {\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$

$$
\mathbf{U} = \exp (A+ F_{01}\gamma_0\gamma_1 + F_{02}\gamma_0\gamma_2+F_{03}\gamma_0\gamma_3 + F_{12}\gamma_1\gamma_2+F_{13}\gamma_1\gamma_3 +F_{23}\gamma_2\gamma_3 + B\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3)
$$

how can I link this to ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$?

---

Once the isomorphism is established, my final goal is to eliminate or constrain terms of ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ such that it is reduced to ${\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R})$.

---

my attempt so far.

Step 1: understand that GL(2,R) can be represent by $\exp(A+X\sigma_x+Y\sigma_y+B\sigma_x\sigma_y)$.

Step 2:
To get the representation in step 1, I start with:
$$
\mathbf{U} = \exp (A+ F_{01}\gamma_0\gamma_1 + F_{02}\gamma_0\gamma_2+F_{03}\gamma_0\gamma_3 + F_{12}\gamma_1\gamma_2+F_{13}\gamma_1\gamma_3 +F_{23}\gamma_2\gamma_3 + B\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3)
$$

I eliminate $F_{03}\to 0,F_{12}\to 0,F_{13}\to 0,F_{23}\to 0$, and pose $\gamma_0\gamma_1\sigma_x, \gamma_0\gamma_2=\sigma_y$. I get:

$$
\mathbf{U} = \exp (A+ F_{01}\sigma_x + F_{02}\sigma_y+ B\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3)
$$

At this point, I do not know what to do with $B\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3$. Since this is a pseudo-scalar in 4D, is it sufficient to leave it as is for the 2D case? If not, then I'm afraid I do not know how to convert $B\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3$ to a 2D version $B\sigma_x\sigma_y$.

Comment: I have attempted to ask this question a few times, but my question contained defects. I am including them as a reference.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4645306/188569
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4644368/188569

I have the question now. Thank you for those who have help me clarify it. I apologize if this is too much - although I point out that each question involves different groups and thus are technically unique and distinct.

Comment: Perhaps this will be helpful: First, because all quadratic forms over $\mathbb C$ are equivalent we can say $$S = \mathrm{Spin}^c(3,1) \cong \mathrm{Spin}^c(W)$$ where we give $W = \mathbb C^2\oplus(\mathbb C^2)^*$ the canoncial quadratic form $(v + v^*)^2 = v^*(v)$. There is a canoncial injective group homomorphism from $\mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb C)$ into the Lipschitz group of $W$ and we have $$\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb C) \to \mathrm{GLip}(W) \cong \mathbb C^\times\times S.$$

Comment: However, the determinant becomes the spinor norm in this Lipschitz group, so restricting to $\mathbb R^+\times S$ will only correspond to elements of $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb C)$ with positive real determinant; note though that this contains $\mathrm{GL}^+(2,\mathbb R)$ as a subgroup, so we have an injection $$\mathrm{GL}^+(2,\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R^+\times S = \mathbb R^+\times\mathrm{Spin}^c(3,1).$$

Comment: Correction: I should have said the *even* Lipschitz group $\mathrm{GLip}^{(0)}(W)$.